# In Java, can the this/super keywords represent anything other than classes/enums?

Tags: java, this, anonymous-class, super

I've noticed that:

```
class A {
    ClassB b = new ClassB() { // anonymous class
        /* some expression using this */
    }
}
```

Whenever I use the `this` keyword inside an anonymous class, the `this` refers to the enclosing outer class/enum and not to the anonymous class.

Does this mean `this` can never represent an anonymous class? Just "normal" classes and enums?

Also, can `this` or `super` represent an interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement about using `this` is incorrect.  When you use `this` inside an anonymous class, it always refers to the anonymous class.  It never refers to the enclosing outer class unless you use `OuterClassName.this`.

`this` or `super` can never represent an interface, since an interface cannot have defined methods.

Answer (score 6):

Your initial assumption is wrong - `this` always represents the current instance, that is the instance of the current class, even if it's anonymous.

Comment: I think you mean "`this` always represents the current **instance**."

Comment: How can I be sure that is true?

Comment: @John: it is true because [it's part of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.3).

Answer (score 0):

Use `A.this` from the inner class.

And it cannot represent an interface, because you cannot define anynomous non-static classes within interfaces, because there wil never be an instance of the interface.

EDIT: Clarified by adding info from the comment.

Comment: strictly speaking, an interface can contain a static field, which can have an initializer, which can contain an anonymous class (however the anonymous class will be static so you cannot refer to `A.this` within it.)

Answer (score 0):

In Java `this` is always the current class even if it is an anonymous class. No, `this` or `super` cannot represent an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous class always extends another class.  Even if you explicitly implement an interface, you are extending `java.lang.Object` and you can only call methods of `java.lang.Object` via `super` calls.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        super.run(); // Error: run() is not a method of java.lang.Object
        super.toString(); // OK: toString() is inherited from java.lang.Object
    }
};
```